# Similarity between particles and antiparticles

Tags: antimatter, particle-physics

I was doing a past exam paper and there was this question: State the similarities between a particle and its antiparticle.

The answer given was: Same mass and rest energy.

I am not too bothered about the question itself -- it's trivial. What I am having trouble with is the answer. In the revision guide I am using it only states one similarity that we need to know: "Same rest mass energy"

So my question is this: Is the phrase "same mass *and* rest energy" redundant, in that the word "mass" is simply referring to the "rest mass energy" (and therefore we can just say "same rest mass energy" like in the revision guide)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, it is redundant.  You could also say they have the same spin and parity.

Comment: I didn't know about those, I'll look them up. Better to get a complete picture than just "work to the exam".

Comment: @user45220: it's probably worded that way because we conventionally give particle masses in energy units e.g. the Higgs is 125GeV.